# Are the tenses of the following piece correct?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing

I almost drowned in the this ocean of tenses. Anyhow, did I make any mistake?

> It was almost two, so I said goodnight to Mom and went back to my
>   room. Once on my bed, I took the gold tooth out of its box and held it
>   up to the ceiling light. My great-great-grandmother had died in her
>   attempt to become immortal, just like many others throughout history.
>   Emperors, dictators, merchants, scientists—they all drowned in the sea
>   of their obsession. But let's say they achieved their goal and became
>   immortal. What good would that have been? Qin Shi Huang would have
>   continued enlisting slaves to build his crazy tomb; Hitler would have
>   continued piling up Jews until making a mountain as tall as Mount
>   Everest; My great-great-grandmother would have—well, I had no idea,
>   but judging from her wackiness, surely nothing good.
>
> And the question also applied to us: to become immortal? What for? To
>   eat at McDonald's until cows went extinct? To buy clothes and
>   electronics until our houses exploded? To fill the Earth with plastic
>   bags, bottles, and metal junk until they flew to its orbit?

Should I have said:

> But let's say they **had** achieved their goal

and ...

> To eat at McDonald's until cows **go** extinct?

and ...

> To buy clothes and electronics until our houses **explode**?

and finally:

> To fill the Earth with plastic bags, bottles, and metal junk until they **fly** to its orbit?

Comment: [Proofreading requests and grammar are off-topic here](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/301/should-we-allow-grammar-proofreading-questions). Closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But, let's say they had achieved their goals, and all become immortal.

Quin Si Haung, continued enlisting slaves to build his crazy tomb. Hiltler, would have continued to pile up Jews, until making a mountain, as tall as, Mount Everest. My great, great, great grandmother, would have, well, I have no idea, but judging from her wackiness, surely nothing good.

And the question, also applies to us, to become immortal, for what? Just to eat at McDonald's until cows go extinct? Just to buy clothes or eletronics until our homes expode? All to fill the Earth with plastic bags, bottles, and metal junk, until thy fly into its orbit?

I'm not sure if all the 'bolding' I just did in my DoctoGo App transferred over and posted above, but at least I tried. My apologies if that portion is missing. Since I was retyping it, I went ahead and made a few minor changes. The above is just my opinion,

I hope the above helps, have a good Day!

Comment: Can you please spell out what you're quoting and bold the punctuation you're adding? I'm having a hard time understanding what your thoughts are here.

Comment: I can spell out my abbreviations; however, as I am using my iphone, that I know of, there isn't a way for me to add the bolded portion you're requesting. I'm working with what amounts to seeing one inch at a time of text and screen. I thought I was doing pretty well with my initial post. *chuckles* Give me a moment and let me see if I can cut/paste my reply.

Comment: I think you missed a comma somewhere.

Comment: @JustaThought You can italicise text by enclosing it in single asterisks (`*italic*`) and boldface text with double asterisks (`**bold**`). I understand the difficulty of writing on a mobile phone. I often do the same, and if there are too many mistakes and too much markup missing, I edit my answers once I'm on my computer.

Comment: User has had almost a month to fix this mess.  Delete it.

Answer (score 1):

> > **had** achieved their goal and **become** immortal

because you're talking about past efforts.

I think the second paragraph should be in [subjunctive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive), which is what you put in your suggested corrections. The narrator is positing a hypothetical future, not a real or hypothetical past.